# How to recognize where my python code creates temp files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcpy, pathos

In my python code i employed several libraries such as pathos, arcpy and numpy. However each time i run the code, about 0.5 GB of free space of my drive C, decreases, although the python file is on another drive. It looks like that the code generates temp files. Now my drive C has not any free space, consequently the code execution results in `OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`. I checked all temp folders on drive C but non of them has a large volume. My question is that is there any way to recognize the direction where files are being written during code execution to find the direction of unwanted temp files?

My OS is Windows 10 and i use python 2.7 .

Comment: do you have disk space again if you reboot? Also note that the location of your script has nothing to do with where data is stored.

Comment: Python itself does not create temp file (at least not in an amount that you would reasonably run out of disk space). Could you try to determine which of the module creates the files? Otherwise, this question is not answerable, IMHO. We can't tell you where any possible Python library could create files.

Comment: @Runorveith rebooting doesn't help.

Comment: I really don't know. I guess the synergy of them, lead to that; pathos is a multiprocessing library and arcpy is a GIS software which creates GIS data. What i ask, is a method to track the directory of data that are being written on DISK in real-time. I can see from task manager that my DISK is working %100 during code execution, however it doesn't show  where does it write on or read from.   @wovano

Comment: @Sina_Alef, you might want to search for an answer (or ask a question) on [superuser](https://superuser.com/) instead, since as currently formulated it sounds more like a general software question than a programming question. To make this on-topic and answerable on SO, you should post the **complete stack trace**, not just the final line that shows the `OSError`. It probably contains relevant information which we can use to help you find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

type echo %temp% on command prompt and it should provide the location of temp directory.

You can change the temp directory location by typing system  in start menu and on system window click on advance system settings this should open system properties dialog, on this dialogue select environment variables and  carefully change the temp environment variable to other drive location for a user.

hope this solves it for you appolgies if it dose not.